# Script runs from standard crontab but not root crontab

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I have a script that starts up a program of mine. I want it to run at boot. It works fine when I put it in crontab -e, but when I put it in sudo crontab -e nothing happens, not even a log file is produced. I wonder what could be the reason for it? I need root access for accessing the serial port in a new version of that program.

The crontab command is:

```
@reboot sh ~/project/tensorrt_demos/launcher2.sh >> ~/project/tensorrt_demos/smart_bike.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Always use fully qualified paths.

Comment: `~` is in the user's context. It will be different for root than for your user account. (But I don't think `sh` understands it anyway.)

Comment: "_I need root access for accessing the serial port_" or you could relax the permissions on the serial port so you didn't need root for running your application

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments the problem was indeed the relative paths. Changing that fixed it.